# Multiple Definition Error in C++ using different files for declaration of function/vector

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, definition, timetable

Sorry for this extensive (body)question, but I'm having an issue trying to separate my *main()* function from my *read.cc* file.

At first I wrote my *main()* in my **read.cc** for it was easier to test and it worked perfectly. Now I'm modularizing my code and using *main()* in a different file (**main.cc**), but I get a "Multiple definition error".

```
//course.h
#ifndef _COURSE_H
#define _COURSE_H

#include "dependencies.h"
class Course{

    public:
        int id;
        std::string id_if;
        std::string name;
        std::string dayTime;
};

#endif


//read.h

#ifndef _READ_H
#define _READ_H

#include "../Classes/course.h"

#include "../Classes/dependencies.h"

using namespace std;

vector <Course*> course;

void readCourse();

void courseCheck(Grade* a, string* temp);
void dispoCheck(Teacher* teacher, string* temp, int day);
const vector<string> explode(const string& s, const char& c);

#endif


//read.cc

void readCourse(){
    Course* inp = new Course();

    ifstream file;
    file.open("../Data/Cursos.csv");

    string temp;

    getline(file, temp, '\n');

    while(file.good()){
            getline(file, temp, ';');      
            inp->id = stoi(temp);

            getline(file, inp->id_if, ';');

            getline(file, inp->name, ';');

            getline(file, inp->dayTime, '\n');
        }

    course.push_back(inp);

}


//main.cc

#include "Input/read.h"

int main(){

    readCourse();

}
```

Error:

```
g++ main.cc Input/read.cc -o exe -lm

/tmp/ccyRgnlM.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `course'
/tmp/ccoTZsnQ.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Read about the keyword `extern`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_COURSE_H`, `_READ_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it's not clear what you are trying to do. Since `course` is only every used inside the `readCourse` method, so could be declared locally inside the function.

I'd assume that (not shown) you want to also use it  in `main`.

Since this is C++ (rather than C) then global variables are best avoided. Your `course` variable should be a static member of a class, possibly the `Course` class itself (and since it's a list, it's better with a plural name). Also, your `readCourse` method should be a static member, e.g.

```
//course.h
class Course{

    public:
        int id;
        std::string id_if;
        std::string name;
        std::string dayTime;

        static std::vector<Course*> courses;
        static void readCourse(); 
};

// course.cc
void Course::readCourse(){
    ...
}

std::vector<Course*> courses; // Defines you single courses object
```

then in `main()` you can access it with:

```
int main(){

    Course::readCourse();

    Course::courses[0]->doSomething();
}
```

}

Comment: In C global variables are best avoided, too. <g> +1.